# how to set cookie in python mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize-python

After sending request to the server

```
    br.open('http://xxxx')
    br.select_form(nr=0)   
    br.form['MESSAGE'] = '1 2 3 4 5'
    br.submit()
```

I get the response title, which has set-cookie

```
Set-Cookie: PON=xxx.xxx.xxx.111; expires=Tue, 17-Mar-2015 00:00:00 GMT; path=/
```

Because mechanize seems to be not able to remember the cookie, so I want to set cookie for br. How can I do it?

```
    cj = mechanize....?
    br.set_cookiejar(cj)
```

I have no idea.
Please help

Answer (score 6):

I think that this should do what you want:

```
import Cookie
import cookielib
cookiejar =cookielib.LWPCookieJar()

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_cookiejar(cookiejar)
cookie = cookielib.Cookie(version=0, name='PON', value="xxx.xxx.xxx.111", expires=365, port=None, port_specified=False, domain='xxxx', domain_specified=True, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=True, discard=False, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={'HttpOnly': False}, rfc2109=False)
cookiejar.set_cookie(cookie)
```

Answer (score 5):

you can also add a preexisting cookie manually with the addheaders method from mechanize's browser class.

```
br.addheaders = [('Cookie','cookiename=cookie value')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import mechanize
import cookielib

br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
```

Comment: thanks. I tried it before posted my question. It does not work. I think I need to pass Set-Cookie: PON=xxx.xxx.xxx.111 to the br. But I dont know how.

Comment: There is another way to set the cookiejar: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6681299/190597).

Comment: @unutbu I think that this is the link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596857/how-do-i-manually-add-more-cookies-to-a-session-which-already-has-cookies-set-in] that you intended to give.

Answer (score 1):

To set a cookie with python mechanize, first grab websites cookies and save them to file "cookies.lwp":

```
import mechanize, cookielib
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.open('https://www.somesite.com')
cj.save(filename="cookies.lwp", ignore_discard=False, ignore_expires=False)
```

You can now set any cookie in "cookies.lwp" to whatever value you want and then load them back into your browser:

```
cj.load(filename="modified_cookies.lwp", ignore_discard=False, ignore_expires=False)
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.open('https://www.yoursitehere.com')
for cookie in cj:
    print cookie
```

This video will walk you through it [How To Modify Cookies with Python Mechanize](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BM-xCsYoAO0)

Answer (score 0):

You can add cookies the better way using the `set_simple_cookie` function.

Considering your cookies are in json,

```json
{
    "domain": ".example.com",
    "expirationDate": 1651137273.706626,
    "hostOnly": false,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "name": "SecureExampleId",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "strict",
    "secure": true,
    "session": false,
    "storeId": null,
    "value": "v%3D2%26mac%..."

}
```

```py
import http.cookiejar

cookiejar = http.cookiejar.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cookiejar)

br.set_simple_cookie(cookie['name'], cookie['value'], cookie['domain'], cookie['path'])

response = br.open(url)
print(cookiejar._cookies)
```