# .set_function ---- is this method or anything?

Tags: python, browser, mechanize, cookielib

sorry for poor english.
I'm now reading python's cookbook and trying to mechanize.
then,there are codes I can't understand.
this:mechanize

```
import mechanize
def printCookies(url):
browser = mechanize.Browser()
cookie_jar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
browser.set_cookiejar(cookie_jar)
<skipped>
```

well.... `in "browser.set_cookiejar(cookie_jar)"`, what "`.set_cookiejar(cookie_jar)`" does?

I think browser and cookie_jar are instance.
then,at the thought of it,
`browser.set_cookiejar(cookie_jar)` meaning I insert instance into anoher instance....????? my brain is about to overflow.

Comment: You may find this helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459217/how-to-set-cookie-in-python-mechanize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It calls the `set_cookiejar` method of the object bound to `browser`, passing it the object in `cookie_jar` as the first supplied argument. What does that method do? Well, that's what the library documentation is for.

Comment: Ahh I see what I asked...anyway thanks for answering.